# GUI problems after checking database

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdbc

im having a few bugs now that i have gone into testing. basically i have a client add frame and a main menu frame. on the client add frame i have save and save and exit. for some reason when i enter the same client name twice and click save and exit my program picks up that the client already exists in the database and goes back to the main menu but it does not draw correctly all i get is a white screen. below is my code for the save and exit button, and main menu methods.

Save and exit button from Client add form.

```
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //##DECLARES FILEPATH##
        String filePath = "C://Users/Chris/java/Tutorials GUI/2.Login page with Database/Login1/Login1.accdb";

        //##PULL FILEPATH FROM ABOVE##
        String db = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+filePath;
        Connection connect = null;
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            /// CONNECTION  MADE
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //try below because i was having trouble passing a boolean from a check box.
        Boolean meeting = false;
        Byte a = 0;
        String yn = "No";
        try{
            String clientName = t.getText();
            if (t1.isSelected()){
                meeting = true;
                a = 1;
                yn = "Yes";
            }
            else{
                meeting = false;
                a = 0;
                yn = "No";
            }
            try ( //// WORKING 
                    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ClientTable(ClientName,Meeting)VALUES('"+clientName+"','"+yn+"')")) {
               //statement.setString(1,clientName);
               //statement.setString(2,yn);
                statement.executeUpdate();
                statement.close();
                connect.close();
                System.out.println("Success!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client added to database returning to main menu.");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client name already in Database!");
            System.out.println("Error" + ex);


        }
        adcFrame.setVisible(false); // makes current frame invisible to user.
        mainMenu(); // goes to main menu frame.
        t.setText(""); // emptys text fields on current frame incase we recall it.
        qcount(); //Calls a count method for use further on in program
        }
    });
```

main menu methods.

```
private void mainMenu(){
    if (mmDraw== true){
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }else{
    //Create and set up the window.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Set up the content pane.
    mainMenuPain(frame.getContentPane());
    //Display the window.
    //frame.setSize(900,900);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    mmDraw=true;
    }
}
```

other main menu setup.

```
private void mainMenuPain(Container pane) {

  // pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
JButton adc = new JButton("Add Client");
JButton adf = new JButton("Add File");
JButton adtf = new JButton("Add Todo To File");
JButton ttdl = new JButton("Todays Todo List");
JButton fftl = new JButton("Find Files Todo list");

    logout.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
        frame.setVisible(false);
        loginframe.setVisible(true);
    });

    adf.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        try{
        frame.setVisible(false);
        if (adfDraw == false){
            fileFrame();
            adfDraw = true;
        }
        else{
            adfFrame.setVisible(true);
            adfDraw = true;
        }
        }catch(Exception exe){
            System.out.println("ERROR:"+exe);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    adtf.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{
        frame.setVisible(false);
        if (adtdDraw==false){
            todoFrame();
            adtdDraw=true;  
            adtdFrame.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            adtdFrame.setVisible(true);
            adtdDraw=true;
        }
    });

    adc.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        if (adcDraw == false){
            clientFrame();
            adcDraw = true;
        }
        else{
            adcFrame.setVisible(true);
            adcDraw = true;
        }
   });

    fftl.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{
        frame.setVisible(false);
        if (fftlDraw==false){
            findtodoFrame();
            fftlDraw=true;  
            fftlFrame.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            fftlFrame.setVisible(true);
            fftlDraw=true;
        }
    });
    ttdl.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{
        check();
       frame.setVisible(false);

           todays();
           tdDraw=true;
           tdFrame.setVisible(true);

    });

pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

//natural height, maximum width
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;  

int buttonMovement = 0;
int numButtons = 6;

while (buttonMovement < numButtons){
c.gridy = buttonMovement;
buttonMovement = buttonMovement + 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 40;
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridwidth = 5;
    if (buttonMovement == 1){
        pane.add(adc, c);
    }
    if (buttonMovement == 2){
        pane.add(adf, c);
    }
    if (buttonMovement ==3){
        pane.add(adtf, c);    
    }
    if (buttonMovement ==4){
        pane.add(ttdl, c);   
    }
    if (buttonMovement ==5){
        pane.add(fftl, c);   
    }
    if (buttonMovement ==6){
        pane.add(logout, c);   
    }

}
```

}

its a really baffling one to me so apologies if its an easy fix! also i have a Booleans setup for each frame if that frame has been drawn previously the boolean becomes true. and on reinstatement of that frame the setVisible is set only.

thanks

Comment: It's never a good idea to do lengthy tasks in the event dispatching thread (e.g. in an `ActionListener`). While you do long tasks in the EDT, your GUI and input processing is frozen. Do that in another thread, and you should only update the GUI about the progress of the lengthy task being performed in the "background" (in other threads).

Comment: ok thanks im fairly new to java so im sure my program is clunky! So basically should i be having another method to pull data? i can think of a way to do that. i.e pass data variables to a method that will change the SQL code accordingly. my draw functions ect do all the running within the method its self. maybe not such an easy fix after all then :D ill go back to the drawing board :)

Comment: I recommend to read this official Oracle tutorial: Concurrency in Swing (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: ok  will thanks, lots to learn still :)